# Using macroexpand-1 to expand macros within let forms (Practical Common Lisp, Chapter 8, "Plugging the Leaks")

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, practical-common-lisp

In Chapter 8 of Practical Common Lisp, "Plugging the leaks" we define this macro and discover that it leaks through examination with `macroexpand-1`

```lisp
(defmacro do-primes ((var start end) &body body)
  `(do ((,var (next-prime ,start) (next-prime (1+ ,var)))
        (ending-value ,end))
       ((> ,var ending-value))
     ,@body))
```

> The following seemingly innocent call to do-primes doesn't work
> correctly because of this leak:
>
> > (do-primes (ending-value 0 10)   (print ending-value))
> > Neither does this one:
>
> > (let ((ending-value 0))   (do-primes (p 0 10)
> > (incf ending-value p))   ending-value)

I can use `macroexpand-1` on that like so where I've named this macro do-primes4

```lisp
(macroexpand-1 '(do-primes4 (ending-value 0 10)
  (print ending-value)))

(DO ((ENDING-VALUE (NEXT-PRIME 0) (NEXT-PRIME (1+ ENDING-VALUE)))
     (ENDING-VALUE 10))
    ((> ENDING-VALUE ENDING-VALUE))
  (PRINT ENDING-VALUE))
```

However I can't do the same on the second form where the macro call is with the let

```lisp
(macroexpand-1 '(let ((ending-value 0))
  (do-primes4 (p 0 10)
    (incf ending-value p))
  ending-value))

(LET ((ENDING-VALUE 0))
  (DO-PRIMES4 (P 0 10)
    (INCF ENDING-VALUE P))
  ENDING-VALUE)
```

It seems not to actually macro-expand do-primes4. I am using SBCL.

Answer (score 4):

GNU Emacs / SLIME

use <kbd>c-c m-m</kbd> on the form. It invokes the code walker. Result:

```
(LET ((ENDING-VALUE 0))
  (BLOCK NIL
    (LET ((P (NEXT-PRIME 0)) (ENDING-VALUE 10))
      (DECLARE (IGNORABLE P ENDING-VALUE))
      (TAGBODY
    (GO #:G586)
       #:G585
    (TAGBODY (SETQ ENDING-VALUE (+ P ENDING-VALUE)))
    (PROGN (SETQ P (NEXT-PRIME (1+ P))) NIL)
       #:G586
    (IF (> P ENDING-VALUE)
            NIL
            (GO #:G585))
    (RETURN-FROM NIL (PROGN)))))
  ENDING-VALUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two macro-expansion functions, `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1`, http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm. Both expand macros, `macroexpand-1` does one level, `macroexpand` keeps going until it is completely expanded. Both return two values:

1. The expansion
2. A flag which indicates that an expansion occurred

The macro expansion is this:

```
; macro expansion

(macroexpand-1 '(do-primes4 (ending-value 0 10)
   (print ending-value)))
(DO ((ENDING-VALUE (NEXT-PRIME 0) (NEXT-PRIME (1+ ENDING-VALUE)))
     (ENDING-VALUE 10))
((> ENDING-VALUE ENDING-VALUE))
  (PRINT ENDING-VALUE))

; flag
T
```

The expansion is printed first, and then the flag - here `T` to show that an expansion occurred.

The problem with your second example is that the `let` is the first item in the macro-expansion. At the moment you are only attempting to expand the `let` form, with its body returned unchanged:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(let ((ending-value 0)) (do-primes4 (ending-value 0 10)
                                               (print ending-value))))

(LET ((ENDING-VALUE 0))
   (DO-PRIMES4 (ENDING-VALUE 0 10)
      (PRINT ENDING-VALUE)))
NIL
```

The flag takes the value `NIL`, to show that no expansion occurred.

The `let` form expands to itself, because it isn't a macro, with flag `NIL`:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(let ((x 0))))
  (LET ((X 0)))
  NIL
```

Comment: Thank you Francis, I understand now that macroexpand-1 would not expand more than one level deep, and macroexpand will stop at the first non macro form, the let. I wonder if it's possible to do the same test by passing the &optional env for `(let ((ending-value 0)))`

Answer (score 1):

Although, as Rainer Joswig pointed out, you need a code-walker to see what the expansion actually is in this case, and neither `macroexpand-1` more `macroexpand` are code walkers, you don't actually need that to see what the problem is here.  In a form like

```
(let ((ending-value 0))
  (do-primes (p 0 10)
    (incf ending-value p))
  ending-value)
```

You can just expand the `do-primes` form at top-level and then substitute it in, to get the obvious thing:

```
(let ((ending-value 0))
  (do ((p (next-prime 0) (next-prime (1+ p))) (ending-value 10))
      ((> p ending-value))
    (incf ending-value p))
  ending-value)
```

And now it's immediately apparent what the problem is: the `ending-value` you are incrementing is not the binding you think it is.

There are various CL code-walkers out there: I'm not familiar enough with them to recommend one.